# Android-Video View in Fullscreen

Tags: android, video, fullscreen

I am trying to make this VideoView to appear in full screen mode :

```
public class ViewVideo extends Activity {
  private String filename;
  private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.gc();
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        filename = extras.getString("videofilename");
        VideoView vv = new VideoView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(vv);
        vv.setVideoPath(filename);
        vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vv.requestFocus();
        vv.start();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0,"FullScreen");

      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
      switch(item.getItemId()) {
      case INSERT_ID:
          createNote();
      }
      return true;
  }

  private void createNote() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
  }
}
```

The video is playing from sdcard. Only thing is when I click on the full-screen menu button, the application "stops unexpectedly".

Please help me out, how to get the video to run in full screen? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

when you click an menu item. you have to start a New Activity. for that Activity you have to set the theme attribute in the Manifest. set this value that is

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

thats it.

Answer (score 40):

No need of code to play video in full screen mode

#### Apply the following layout format over the xml containing the videoview it will for sure will play the video in full screen mode. as it is running mine :) Hope it helps

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: for performing same thing the above layout can be applied using a code when full screen mode button is to be pressed . it worked great for me.

Comment: this would just fill the available width and height of the application window. you still end up with your applications titlebar and the system icons (date/time battery status etc) at the top. The unspoken assumption here is that he wants the video to fill the *entire* screen.

Comment: Hi javanator i am facing the same problem while playing the video in videoview and run it in tablet. i have used your solution but it still having the center alligned video in tablet and 2 black lines in both left and right side. What to do. here is my question in so.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708457/play-the-video-from-assests-in-videoview-not-in-full-screen-mode-in-tablet

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps it's because you have to add following code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

before `setContentView(your_content_view)` to get rid of app title bar. I know its a very late reply but somebody might find it useful.

Comment: its not perhaps, it is for sure..:)

Comment: 2017 and still useful, never late :P

Answer (score 1):

Due to my experienced, you can only use Relative-Layout View for you video to be stretch on portrait and landscape. Linear-layout view can only stretch video on Landscape, you can try the two view without writing any code and prove my theory

Answer (score 0):

Okey, Let's try like this, this was suitable for my full screen.

```
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Portrait layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Landscape layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```