# Change Activity's theme programmatically

Tags: android

In particular cases I need to remove dialog theme from my activity but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's an example

First activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
}
```

Second activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Manifest excerpt:

```
 <activity android:name="SecondActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

When I run it's still dialog themed.

API10

Thanks.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

As [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme%28int%29) say you have to call `setTheme` before any view output. It seems that `super.onCreate()` takes part in `view` processing.

So, to switch between themes dynamically you simply need to call `setTheme` before `super.onCreate` like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Comment: I had to define a theme as described here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44236460/3211335
And then set it as described by this answer. It works great.

Comment: I use shared preference to save theme but when restarting the app, for a moment the first theme appears then the second theme shown!

Answer (score 61):

user1462299's response works great, but **if you include fragments**, they will use the original activities theme. To apply the theme to all fragments as well you can **override the getTheme()** method of the Context instead:

```
@Override
public Resources.Theme getTheme() {
    Resources.Theme theme = super.getTheme();
    if(useAlternativeTheme){
        theme.applyStyle(R.style.AlternativeTheme, true);
    }
    // you could also use a switch if you have many themes that could apply
    return theme;
}
```

You do not need to call setTheme() in the onCreate() Method anymore. You are overriding every request to get the current theme within this context this way.

Comment: Should getTheme() be overridden in the Activity, or in the respective Fragments? I have implemented this in the Activity, but the Fragments are still using the original Activity theme.

Comment: @saltandpepper Overriding it in the Activity is enough. Make sure your fragment code and layout do not change it again.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the answer provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15496425/494179 did.

Comment: Interesting, how did you include your fragment? Not using a FragmentTransaction within the Activity?

Comment: Through a FragmentTransaction, yes.

Comment: Good point user1269737 so you should make sure that there is no heavy calculation. Simply returning a style within a simple condition case will not affect performance.

Comment: In 2021 this is not a good solution. I have published this code and it appears `getTheme` is called a lot, and `applyStyle` is a relatively heavy operation. On the relatively low end device I can exhaust my app's memory and OOM going in and out of a fragment a handful of times. So either you need to make sure to call `applyStyle` only once, OR just use the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576546/1866373) which these days **does indeed set the theme on fragments** as well and of course is called only once.

Comment: `getTheme` is called all over the shop, so be very careful about making it idempotent. If you are saving a theme to a vm (I've never seen that) I would put it in preferences or some app level context instead

Answer (score 15):

I know that i am late but i would like to post a solution here:

Check the full source code [here](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/10/implementing-users-choice-themeapply.html).

This is the code i used when changing theme using preferences..

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String themeName = pref.getString("prefSyncFrequency3", "Theme1");
if (themeName.equals("Africa")) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);



} else if (themeName.equals("Colorful Beach")) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "set theme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setTheme(R.style.beach);


} else if (themeName.equals("Abstract")) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "set theme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    setTheme(R.style.abstract2);

} else if (themeName.equals("Default")) {

    setTheme(R.style.defaulttheme);

}
```

Please note that you have to put the code before setcontentview..

HAPPY CODING!

Comment: I use shared preference to save theme but when restarting the app, for a moment the first theme appears then the second theme shown!

Answer (score 5):

This one works fine for me :

`theme.applyStyle(R.style.AppTheme, true)`

**Usage:**

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //The call goes right after super.onCreate() and before setContentView()
    theme.applyStyle(R.style.AppTheme, true)
    setContentView(layoutId)
    onViewCreated(savedInstanceState)
}
```

OR using `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Light)`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //The call goes right after super.onCreate() and before setContentView()
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Light)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have used this code to implement dark mode...it worked fine for me...You can use it in a switch on....listener...

```
//setting up Night Mode...
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
//Store current mode in a sharedprefernce to retrieve on restarting app
            editor.putBoolean("NightMode", true);
            editor.apply();
//restart all the activities to apply changed mode...
            TaskStackBuilder.create(getActivity())
                    .addNextIntent(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class))
                    .addNextIntent(getActivity().getIntent())
                    .startActivities();
```

Comment: Question is asked 8 years ago, for now, your solution is used to apply theme, 
but I'm getting a problem, the theme is not applied to all Activities, 
I define some style friend for light and dark, separate for text, these are not applying, even I try restart activities as you mention, Your solution is most closer to my problem,