# Override color value in color.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, colors

Is there a way to override a color that is already set in your color.xml file? For example - I set the background color on the layout to backgroundColor = "@color/background" The value of background = #000000

Can I override the actual color of background in Java and set the @color/background to say - #FFFFFF?

Comment: you mean you want to change the value inside the color file?

Comment: no you cannot do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but rather costly. @color/background is equivalent to R.color.background, where R is your generated class. At runtime, you could [use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection) to make the fields writable, then change them. I'm not really convinced it would work how you want.

A different idea would be to [use themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for the various colors you want, possibly letting the user [switch between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562051/change-activitys-theme-programmatically). That'd keep your design and logic separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));` to set the background color in your Java code. This should override the xml background when it is set in the `android:background` xml tag, it did on my tested table row at least.