# How to override color value in colors.xml?

Tags: android, xml, themes, android-resources

I overwrite some system color which is responsible for the color of the status bar when entering Action Mode in my `colors.xml` file in this manner:

```
<color name="abc_input_method_navigation_guard" tools:override="true">@color/colorPrimaryDark</color>
```

But when I create a new theme, and expose a new color of `colorPrimaryDark`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NewTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
</style>
```

It does not change in `colors.xml` file and in and `"abc_input_method_navigation_guard"` overwrites with old color.
How can I override color value in `colors.xml` in my theme or maybe programmatically?
I tried this but it didnt work for me:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NewTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark" tools:override="true">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Refer these answer hope it will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319900/override-color-value-in-color-xml-file

Comment: It is possible that you want to do `<color name="abc_input_method_navigation_guard" tools:override="true">?att/colorPrimaryDark</color>` i.e. using an attribute instead of the color? In your theme you changed the value of an *attribute* not a color.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for the explanation, I didn't know that in theme changes the attribute value. But unfortunately, this system color takes only a fixed color resources

Answer (score 0):

Colors is where you should create color and give it a name :

colors.xml

```
<color name="abc_input_method_navigation_guard">#000000</color>
```

styles.xml

```
   <style name="AppTheme.NewTheme">
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard</item>
   </style>
```