# Creating 2 activities and view programmatically. I want to create the view of second activity transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have requirement of creating two activities and their layout programmatically. And I want to create something like this,

Create a first activity and with a fixed background and second activity which will have a transparent area at all side so there the view of first activity will be shown.

Right now I am creating one activity and it shows OK.
and 
`setTheme( android.R.style.Theme_Translucent );` 
when i open second activity the view shows with margin but with the plain background and not the transparent view of first activity.

I have set the back ground of second activity like this, `rLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));`
It is showing the grey color at background.

I know a one work around by creating dialog, But it would be better to use activity as per our requirement.

Comment: In place of sencond activity you have to use fragment .

Comment: ok thanks for fast reply, I will look for that.
But still if there is any way to do it by activity,
It will be very nice if its possible.

Comment: I think you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562051/change-activitys-theme-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transparent theme in styles and then use that style for your transparent Activity.

Refer to this answer:
[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Comment: See i have to create a whole layout programmatically without using any layout xml.
so my concern is that 'is it possible to create style programmatically?'
cause i found some answer in stackoverflow that it is not possible.