# how to switch android app theme when an android app run

Tags: android, colors, switch-statement, themes

When my android app run, there is a button or something which let customers to select a color to show on primarycolordack, colorprimary and so on. in others words, i want to change app theme. how to do that?

Comment: Restart Activity and set theme before Activity.onCreate(). This answer may helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/11576546/5183999

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you android mead it simple, there is a method for that inside the activity class:

```
setTheme(android.R.style.MyTheme);
```

You'll have to call this method inside on create before the super command like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.MyTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```