# what to use if i have long updating ui thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, threadpool, android-runonuithread

I have a project which a activity have more than 1000 buttons. i am updating the background color of these buttons after taking the color information from the database. This whole process is a very big process and took 8 seconds to load my activity.
i have implement Asynctask for that but the problem is with this exception because "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views". because my long operation is on that part **where i am updating my UI elements**

After that i have implemented a thread that runs on UIthread for updating ui elements, this works fine according to its function, this thread update my ui but it stucks my application for 5-6 seconds. and then i thought of implementing a progress dialog for that 5-6 seconds. but if i implement progress dialog on runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){} it doesn't work. because updating ui and progress dialog runs on the same time. so progress dialog flashes for few milliseconds. and the activity still remains the same as it was before. 
I don't know that to use for updating ui if they took long time to update.

This is my code where i update by ui elements from database.

> 

```
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                Button btn = list.get(i);
                Platform p = db.setplatformncolor(btn.getTag().toString());
                String color = p.getColor();


                if (color.equals("red")) {
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }


                if (color.equals("green")) {

                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 176, 80));

                }
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.!!

Comment: Can't you update your buttons before adding screen?

Comment: how can i update them. its  in layout xml.

Comment: You can create them programmatically and then use parent.addView(btn); method. Otherwise, you have to work on ui thread and it is going to freeze screen eventually.

Comment: your mehod make some sense, but i have a big working project. this method will change my entire flow of the project. so i can't use it. but thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the for loop take two long time, try to just put the loop in thread and setBackgroundColor in ui thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            final Button btn = list.get(i);
            Platform p = db.setplatformncolor(btn.getTag().toString());
            String color = p.getColor();


            if (color.equals("red")) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                });
            }


            if (color.equals("green")) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 176, 80));
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a green button theme and a red button theme like this

```
<style name="RedButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
</style>

<style name="GreenButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
</style>
```

Then just apply the theme. The system will automatically apply your background color for all buttons. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576546/2593148) if want more details about themes switching.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask can fix your problem. the most time consuming operation in this code is

```
db.setplatformncolor(btn.getTag().toString());
```

so you have to move this line into `doInBackground()` method and after adding to DB call `publishProgress()` also you should implement `onProgressUpdate()` and change your button backgrounds in this method

Answer (score 0):

this might be a bit tricky and complex solution for starters , but is efficient and applicable to your requirement.

Android has launched DataBinding Library, which will update your XML dynamically , try it

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: thanks for this method. but @周斌佳 code is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

If your app api level >=11 and if you only need two colors, then you can create a drawable xml for your buttons' background like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_activated="false" />
<item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_activated="true"/>
```

and then just change `btn.setActivated(true/false);`

Comment: i have more than 12 colors for button