# Change DarkMode Programmatically

Tags: android, view, color-scheme, android-night-mode, android-dark-theme

This is my style in attr_styles.xml

```
<style name="AttrStyles" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="calendarAppointmentView">@style/calendar_appointment_view</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/white_style</item>
</style>
```

And I have 2 colors.xml files. 1 is in values, the other in values-night.

If I select from phone settings DarkMode on or off, it works.
BUT I want to have a Spinner in my app, to have: AUTO, ON, OFF.
How can I force it to show the light colors (values) or to show the dark colors (values-night) based on that spinner?

I tried in my App.kt class (Application class) to call onCreate() this:

```
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

or

```
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

But nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60149102/11158194 check this may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for your qestion for about 2 minutes, I came across a similar question that pretty much has the [answer you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562051/change-activitys-theme-programmatically). It seems like you have to use the method setTheme.

Comment: You are missing the point. I want a Spinner to select and force which mode I want.
setTheme I can set to DayNight and it will take the mode based on DarkTheme ON or OFF. OK, if it's off, I setTheme to android.R.style.theme . and it's light mode on. 
But how can I set the theme to forcefully use the values-night. AKA force dark mode on , even if settings are on light