# Is it possible to set the night mode only for a single Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am setting the night mode in onCreate of an activity. So every single activity in the app turns to night mode and all the previous activities gets recreated.  But I need only that particular activity to be in night mode and all other activities to be in light mode. How to achieve this ? Below line of code I am using in oncreate of an activity to set to night mode.

`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)`

Comment: why not just turn it off in every other activity ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody You mean to set AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO) in every other activity?

Comment: yes, i don't think there's another way of doing it, you could consider making a base class or something to make this easier

Comment: calling `setDefaultNightMode` with opposite mode than currently set makes all `Activities` on stack recreate, thats very inefficient and may lead to losing some data (e.g. scroll position or texts in `EditText`s, depends on saving instance state implementation)

Answer (score 5):

---

### Try This to Set Modes Only for Single Activity

---

## Light Mode

```
getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

## Dark Mode

```
getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

## System Default

```
getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
```

Comment: This is throwing an exception that 
StrictMode              com.google.android.gms.persistent    D  StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.UnsafeIntentLaunchViolation: Launch of unsafe intent

Answer (score 0):

sadly you don't have option for switching only one `Activity` into dark mode leaving all others in light. `setDefaultNightMode` is one and only method and it is working for whole `Application` and all `Activities` running in it.

you have to make two separated styles/themes for this one `Activity` and switch its theme programmatically ([here you find out how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562051/change-activitys-theme-programmatically)) or if this one `Activity` is always dark then set its theme straight inside manifest

Answer (score 0):

you can change the theme of the activity in the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> AppCompatDelegate::setLocalNightMode(mode: Int)

Global night mode (effect to whole application):

```
//Light  
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
//Night
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

Local night mode(effect to single used activity):

```
//Light  
AppCompatDelegate.setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
//Night
AppCompatDelegate.setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

(Sorry, my English is not good!!)

Comment: there is no such method setLocalNightMode() in AppCompatDelegate