# Android Splash Screen with user defined theme

Tags: android, splash-screen

```
I have migrated my splash screen to Android splash screen to support android 12. App uses user theme based on color. The theme was set onCreate() method of activity with setTheme() method.
```

After migration, I can set only one theme through XML attribute "postSplashScreenTheme".
How to set "postSplashScreenTheme" programmatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576546/19491703 try this link

Comment: try [```Activity.getSplashScreen().setSplashScreenTheme(int themeId)```](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/SplashScreen#setSplashScreenTheme(int))

Comment: @BeantSingh I am using setTheme() to change theme. That is working ok for upto Android 11. but after migrating to Android Splash Screen for Android 12 Compatibility only option available for theme after splash is to specify "postSplashScreenTheme" from XML.

Comment: @Ayaka_Ago I need to set app main theme programmatically not the Splash Screen theme.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `postSplashScreenTheme` programmatically not possible as of now. But we can change to custom theme by `setTheme(customTheme)` immediately after `installSplashScreen()`.