# Setting theme for an fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-theme, android-fragmentactivity

I've got the following two themes:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyDemoApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/purple_500</item>
</style>

<!-- Base application theme with a prominent app bar incl. image -->
<style name="Theme.MyDemoApp.Prominent.Image" parent="Theme.MyDemoApp">

    <!-- Transparent status bar, so that the image extents to the status bar-->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

The theme `Theme.MyDemoApp` is being used my my application or actually my entire application.

One activity opens a special fragment. The fragment is using a prominent app bar with an image, where the image is also displayed on the status bar.
Thus, I've created an own theme called `Theme.MyDemoApp.Prominent.Image` which enables me to display the image on the status bar.

Since the fragment will be called from different actities AND fragments, I want to set the `Theme.MyDemoApp.Prominent.Image` to the fragment.
I've looked many solutions to set the theme to fragment such as:

1)

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    context.setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyDemoApp_Prominent_Image);
    super.onAttach(context);
}
```

2. 

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
    final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_MyDemoApp_Prominent_Image);

    //clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo_appbar_image, container, false);
}
```

3. 

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.Theme_MyDemoApp_Prominent_Image, true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo_appbar_image, container, false);
}
```

4. 

Setting the theme directly in the fragment xml file

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/Theme.MyDemoApp.Prominent.Image"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyDemoApp.Prominent.Image"
    >
<!-- bla bla bla bla -->
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

However, NONE of the above tried solutions worked for me. The theme won't change aka the status bar is not transparent.
If I put the fragment theme parameters into the activity theme, it work's like a charm, but that is not what I'm planning to do.....

What might the problem be and any idea how can I set the theme in my fragment correctly?

Comment: @snachmsm thanks for the input, unfortunately it wasn't a success. It seems that the issue is ```android:statusBarColor``` and ```android:windowTranslucentNavigation``` cause it seems the the color attributes will get changed(if i override it in my fragment theme) , but not the statusbar color

Comment: posted as answer with some explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to `return localInflater.inflate(...` in 2. try

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
    final Context contextThemeWrapper = 
        new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_MyDemoApp_Prominent_Image);

    //clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
    return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo_appbar_image, container, false);
}
```

edit: now I see problem more clearly...

you are trying to set `statusBarColor` and `windowTranslucentNavigation` - those are params for `Activity`, not `Fragment`. so your theme should be applied to `Activity`, setting up theme on `Fragment` or `View` layer/level (kind-of child of `Fragment`, which is a child of `Activity`) by `Context` wrapping or setting programmtacially/by XML is just "too low", hosting `Activity` just won't apply these attributes

so you have to set up `Theme` for whole `Activity` - translucent status bar when your `Fragment` shows up and returning to default (black?) color when detaching it. but you can set `Theme` for whole `Activity` programmatically only by [calling `setTheme(` before `super.onCreate(` call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562051/change-activitys-theme-programmatically), so only at very beginning, when you probably won't be sure that translucent-status-`Fragment` will be shown... (e.g. it may show on some click during runtime)

so you need to restart `Activity` then, with some additional flag customising `setTheme(`, also your `Fragment` should pop-up then at start... you may use `Bundle` passed for `Intent` starting this `Activity` again just after `finish()` call

I do believe that this is just too much effort and your `Fragment` should be in fact another `Activity` with this transparent-status theme set up by XML, optionally it may be some extension of some [transparet-Activity-theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android) instead of your `"Theme.MyDemoApp"`

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. :) 
Now it makes sence why my approach didn't work.

You mentioned that I should replace the fragment with an activity (which works perfect btw thanks to you) , but wouldn't fragments be better, even in this case if the fragment approach worked?
Cause I call the fragment, or now the activity, from different fragments and since fragments are meant to be reusable code, I decided to go for it. Cause now I have many fragments and one "random" activity in this case which kinda looks strange.

Comment: well, `Fragment`s are "pieces of `Activity`" and your purpose is to change param of an `Activity`, not some interal piece of it, so for this you need to have specially stylled `Activity`. Note that you still can have all your logic as `Fragment` and you may still open it in any `Activity`, but statusbar won't change, as "`Activity` decides". But in some circumstances you may instead start some "dummy-transparent-Activity" passing to it your `Fragment` (or some data indicating `Fragment` init inside), then status bas will be transparent

Comment: And here you have the idea of fragmenting and reusability - your `Fragment` can be attached in multiple ways/statusbar-colors, but you probably need only transparent one (so new `Activity`), and also dummy-transparent-`Activity` may take and run some another `Fragment` showing it with translucent/no statusbar