# Playing a small resolution video on a higher resolution Device, in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, video, fullscreen, adt, stretch

I have a `480x360` mp4 video nested inside a fullscreen VideoView. What I want is to play it on a higher resolution physical device on fullscreen. I don't mind if the video gets distorted by stretching it to the dimensions of the device screen. I just want it **fullscreen**.

My Java code is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

       VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);


       vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });


       Uri url=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+ R.raw.bubblessd );

       vv.setVideoURI(url);
       vv.start();
       vv.requestFocus();

    }
}
```

And my activity XML is this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and your question is ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VideoView Full screen in android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310764/videoview-full-screen-in-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

- If you use VideoView, the better solution in this case to keep the aspect ratio is fixing a black background and cropCenter your videoView. You can fitXY your videoView but it will be lose the original aspect ratio.
  Check this link out:  [http://blog.gemserk.com/2013/01/22/our-solution-to-handle-multiple-screen-sizes-in-android-part-one/][1]
- If you use SurfaceView, (for me the best option), you can use the method:

  yourSurfaceVideo.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);

to adapt your video to the space yo want. Hope it helps!