# How Can I force videoview to play video always in landscape mode

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation, android-videoview, device-orientation

I want my video to played in landscape mode.when i am putting orientations in activity it makes only mediaplayer in landscape mode but video view still remains in potrait mode.

Here is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        />


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/deleteVideo"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:src="@mipmap/delete_video"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/saveVideo"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:src="@mipmap/save_video"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: change the containing screen activity orientation to landscape mode from manifest or from oncreate method programmatically

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4452597/3758024

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VideoView Full screen in android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310764/videoview-full-screen-in-android-application)