# Android fullscreen activity with videoview

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I am to build an activity to play video in full screen mode by using the auto generated full screen activity. Now when the screen been touched only the status bar and the nav buttons show. The media controller only show on second screen touch while the status bar and nav buttons are visible. Also the right end of the media controller is show cut off by the sysn nav. Anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776254/android-video-view-in-fullscreen

Comment: I want full screen with status bar and system nav to show/hide with a time out.

Comment: So see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10909579/3828773 and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072338/3828773

Comment: I already know how to hide show status bar and system nav with screen touch. The problem now is the MedicaController only shows on two touches.