# Custom VideoView in full Screen

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a Video view in height=400 and width= 300 and its playing properly with this attributes.
My task is to play video  in full screen mode in portrait mode on Double Tap and also its go to its original size on double tap when it playing in full screen mode.
I also tried with this

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics); 
int height =displaymetrics.heightPixels; 
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params  =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)uservides.getLayoutParams;    
params.width = width;
params.height = height; 
uservideos.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: different solutions exist : change your layout to take fullScreen, start a new activity with only the VideoView, change our current VideoView parent so it's the root View so it will take all activity screen.

Comment: can u gave me a snippet of a code so i can  get idea from that

Comment: depend of what you want. If you want a basic fullScreen it chaging your layout but if you want a true fullScreen it's the activity solution. 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776254/android-video-view-in-fullscreen

Comment: yes i just want a true full screen mode