# How to make custom videoview with fullscreen view?

Tags: android, youtube, android-gradle-plugin, video-player

I am making video player like YouTube app player.but issue in that i can't do full-screen player same as YouTube. can anyone suggest me any custom video player `gradle` or library?

Comment: this will help you. https://github.com/rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776254/android-video-view-in-fullscreen